# Spanish Expressway Toll Refund

Tags: driving, spain, refunds, tolls

Recently I travelled on the tolled expressway from Valencia to Alicante Autopista AP-7 in Spain. I paid the toll amount with my card from N26. Two weeks later I see the amount has been refunded back to me.

Has anyone faced this? Why would the company refund me back the toll money? Is it a policy from my card provider N26 or the toll collector? What would have happened if I paid by cash?

I was using a car from the rental service.

Comment: Did you check the toll was not charged twice? In that case they could have refunded one of the payments. Do you maybe have an electronic toll device in your car? Some of those are interoperable in several countries. Does your statement state anything specific regarding the refund? You may want to call your bank to inquire, they may have more details (i.e. whether this is a merchant-initiated refund, or a bank-initiated cancellation).

Comment: I am not sure about Spain, but in e.g. Norway, toll charges are often covered by the rental company (that is, included as a flat-fee add-on to the rental price). May that be the case here as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The portion of the AP-7 that runs from Alicante to Tarragona reverted to the Spanish government on the first of January of 2020. Starting that day the motorway is now free to use without tolls.

As the infrastructure can't be dismantled immediately, it may happen that they were still charging drivers a few days after it reverted and they have to reimburse you afterwards.

Last year I traveled on another Spanish motorway that had just reverted and they simply left the barriers open. There was a big queue as foreigners who couldn't read the signs tried to use the deactivated toll machines, if you don't speak Spanish you may also have missed those and paid anyway.